# allow insecure registry in host provisioned with docker-machine

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Is there anyway to configure **--allow-insecure-ssl** for docker's deamon created with docker-machine.

**commands:**

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev 
eval "$(docker-machine env dev)"
docker run myregistry:5000/busybox:latest echo 'hello world'
```

**output:**

```
Unable to find image 'myregistry:5000/busybox:latest' locally
2015/06/04 16:54:17 Error: v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get          
https://myregistry:5000/v1/_ping: EOF. If this private  
registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, 
please add `--insecure-registry myregistry:5000` to the 
daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the 
registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA 
certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/myregistry:5000/ca.crt
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you are running docker-machine version v0.2 stable, you can't set docker option in light way. But in next version v0.3 this problem was resolved with the creation parameters.

At this moment this feature it's on RC1,then you can use a version [v0.3.0-RC-1](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/tag/v0.3.0-rc1) or wait for delivery the next stable version v0.3.0(tentatively Jun.16).

Then use parameter `--engine-insecure-registry` to set `--allow-insecure-ssl` for docker's daemon, for example:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --engine-insecure-registry myregistry:5000 dev
```

After that you can execute:

```
docker run myregistry:5000/busybox:latest echo 'hello world'
```

Additionally you can read about it on [project doc](https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/master/docs/index.md).

Comment: New to docker and I am using 1.8.1 at the moment. Tried to do what you suggested but got this

Unable to find image 'myregistry:5000/busybox:latest' locally
Pulling repository myregistry:5000/busybox
Error while pulling image: Get http://myregistry:5000/v1/repositories/busybox/images: dial tcp: lookup myregistry: no such host

Comment: tried with IP of registry
curl http://192.168.99.100:5000/v1/_ping
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 5000: Connection refused

Comment: myregistry is the know name of host on your network, if your hostname is: registry.domain.com your need replace myregistry for it. Also you need resolve hostname, you can try: ping yourhostname.domain.com?

Comment: I just got it to work by getting frustrated and shutting down and removing all images, closing all terminal windows. After which I created two new docker machines with 
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --engine-insecure-registry ip.add.ress:5000 dev
command. 
and it worked... 
I am guess some setting was set somewhere that caused all this grief.

I like docker so far but boy it is unstable...

Comment: This is currently undocumented and you are my hero. I will sing songs about you.

Comment: All this was extremely helpful. Worked for me after having private repository pushes failing.

Answer (score 40):

If you want to add insecure registries to a docker-machine that is already created you can update the profile in the running docker VM.

#### Steps

1. SSH into your local docker VM.
   *note: if 'default' is not the name of your docker machine then substitute 'default' with your docker machine name*
   `$ docker-machine ssh {machineName}`
2. Open Docker profile
   `$ sudo vi /var/lib/boot2docker/profile`
3. Add this line to the bottom of the profile file. If EXTRA_ARGS already exists, add the insecure registry flag to the EXTRA_ARGS. Substitute in the path[s] to your registries.

   `EXTRA_ARGS="
   --insecure-registry myserver.pathTo.registry1:5000
   --insecure-registry myserver.pathTo.registry2:5000
   --insecure-registry myserver.pathTo.registry3:5000
   "`
4. Save the profile changes and 'exit' out of the docker-machine bash back to your machine. Then Restart Docker VM substituting in your docker-machine name
   `$ docker-machine restart {machineName}`
5. Pull or push something from your registry to ensure it works

#### My Setup

**docker-machine version :** 0.6.0, build e27fb87
**docker-machine driver :** virtualbox

Comment: This does work for me, but if i restart the machine it seems to lose the setting? Any idea why that might happen?

Answer (score 9):

In case you want to add another registry once your docker-machine has already been created you will have to edit the configuration file:
vim  ~/.docker/machine/machines/dev/config.json

Explained here: https://akrambenaissi.com/2015/11/17/addingediting-insecure-registry-to-docker-machine-afterwards/

Comment: Is it necessary to restart the docker-machine?

Answer (score 7):

env :

- docker daemon :1.12.3
- docker client :1.12.2
- docker api :1.24
- docker-machine :0.8.2

> Before create machine

you can use the args to set one or multi insecure registry and registry mirrors .eg:

**one registry**

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-insecure-registry hostname:5000  --engine-registry-mirror http://hostname:5000 n1
```

**multi registrys**

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-insecure-registry hostname:5000 --engine-insecure-registry hostname:5001  --engine-registry-mirror http://hostname:5000 n1
```

> After create the machine

you can edit the /var/lib/boot2docker/profile to add the registrys and mirrors

```
docker-machine ssh [machine-name]
vi /var/lib/boot2docker/profile
```

add the registry and mirrors to the EXTRA_ARGS

```
EXTRA_ARGS='
--label provider=virtualbox
--insecure-registry hostname:5000
--insecure-registry hostname:5001
--registry-mirror   http://hostname:5000
--registry-mirror   http://hostname:5001
```

now you need to restart the machine and check it

```
docker-machine restart [machine-name] 
docker info
```

> this method  doesn`t work after create the machine

edit $USER/.docker/machine/machines/default/config.json

```
"EngineOptions": {
    "InsecureRegistry": [
        "XXX.XXX.virtual"
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 5):

edit $USER/.docker/machine/machines/default/config.json

```
    "EngineOptions": {
        "InsecureRegistry": [
            "XXX.XXX.virtual"
        ],
    }
```