# Can I pass --max-concurrent-downloads as a flag?

Tags: docker

I'm working with a poor internet connection and trying to pull and run a image.

I wanted to download one layer at a time and per documentation tried adding a flat --max-concurrent-downloads like so:

```
docker run --rm -p 8787:8787 -e PASSWORD=blah --max-concurrent-downloads=1 rocker/verse
```

But this gives an error:

> unknown flag: --max-concurrent-downloads See 'docker run --help'.

I tried typing `docker run --help` and interestingly did not see the option --max-concurrent-downloads.

I'm using Docker Toolbox since I'm on a old Mac.

Over here under l there's an option for --max-concurrent-downloads however this doesn't appear on my terminal when typing `docker run --help`

[image]

How can I change the default of downloading 3 layers at a time to just one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull layers one by one in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303784/how-to-pull-layers-one-by-one-in-docker)

Comment: I took a look at the post that you linked to. The accepted solution comments say to edit a file in /etc/docker/ however /etc/docker does not exist in my file structure. The answer further down suggests ```sudo service docker stop``` however this gives me "dockerd: command not found"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This setting needs to be passed to dockerd when starting the daemon, not to the docker client CLI. The dockerd process is running inside of a VM with docker-machine (and other docker desktop environments).

With `docker-machine` that is used in toolbox, you typically pass the engine flags on the `docker-machine create` command line, e.g.

```
docker-machine create --engine-opt max-concurrent-downloads=1
```

Once you have a created machine, you can follow the [steps from these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37860893/596285) to modify the config of an already running machine, mainly:

> 1. SSH into your local docker VM.
>      *note: if 'default' is not the name of your docker machine then substitute 'default' with your docker machine name*   `$
>      docker-machine ssh default`
> 2. Open Docker profile     `$ sudo vi /var/lib/boot2docker/profile`

Then in that profile, you would add your `--engine-opt max-concurrent-downloads=1`.

---

Newer versions of docker desktop (along with any Linux install) make this much easier with a configuration menu daemon -> advanced where you can specify your daemon.json entries like:

```
{
  "max-concurrent-downloads": 1
}
```

Comment: ***NOT WORKING***, 
I set max-concurrent-downloads from the settings for docker engine but after restart and pull the image still getting multiple downloads.

Answer (score 18):

From the official documentation: (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#concurrent-downloads)

You can pass `--max-concurrent-downloads` during a pull operation.

You can set `--max-concurrent-downloads` with [the dockerd command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/).

If you're using the docker Desktop GUI for Mac or Windows:

You can edit the .json file directly in docker engine settings:

[image: Docker engine configs]